# golang dispatcher using map and channels

Tags: design-patterns, go, dispatcher, goroutine

I try design a dispatcher using go in a concurrency situation, the dispatcher needs to dispatch the message to its dedicated worker which only treat one kind of messages (or workers), ex:

- worker type A only processes the message type A
- worker type B only processes the message type B
- etc.,

As I can add/remove dynamically the dedicated worker treating different types of messages. Now I need a message pattern to do so with only goroutine and channel. I plan to have a channel -- a pool of same type workers, and put the channels in a map, so I can distribute message by type according to the keys in map, if the worker for treating message C is not exist, it will just dispatch the message to garbage channel for non-treating, and the same type of workers can process the same type of messages concurrently.  I am not sure if it is a better design or not, any suggestion?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you really need channel to be used like "workers pool"? Why simply not to use a single channel with messages, and as many as you need workers that will receive messages, and will send it to related "processor function" by extracted message type?

Comment: maybe the worker pool part is little bit over-engineering :(

Comment: Why don't you just launch a new groutine each time you get a message of that they? Whats the advantage of having a dedicated worker which waits around to do work?